# WP_Error with multiple form validation message

Tags: plugins, wp-error

I'm working on a front-end form plug-in and having trouble getting validation error message work with `WP_Error`. I spent hours to find a problem but still have no idea.

Below code is actually working but I really don't think I should use `return false;` underneath content validation error message.

```
/*
**  Process data from front end form
    http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post
*/
function write_here_add_new_post() {
    if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "write_here_new_post") {

        $title =  wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['title']);
        $content = $_POST['content'];
        $postdate = $_POST['date'];
        $gmtpostdate = $_POST['date'];
        $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];
        $cat  = $_POST['cat'];

        // Server side validation
        if ($title == '') {
            write_here_errors()->add('title_not_vaild', __('Title not valid'));
        }
        if ($content == '') {
            write_here_errors()->add('content_not_vaild', __('Content not valid'));
            return false;
        }
        if (!$postdate) {
            $postdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $gmtpostdate = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        }

        // Add the content of the form to $post as an array
        $new_post = array(
            'post_title'    => $title,
            'post_content'  => $content,
            'post_category' => array($cat),     // Default empty.
            'tags_input'    => array($tags),    // Default empty.
            'post_status'   => 'publish',       // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc. Default 'draft'.
            'post_date'     => $postdate,       // The time post was made.
            'post_date_gmt' => $gmtpostdate     // The time post was made, in GMT.
        );

        //save the new post and return its ID
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

        // This will redirect you to the newly created post (Using GUID)
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        wp_redirect($post->guid);
        exit();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'write_here_add_new_post');

// used for tracking error messages
function write_here_errors(){
    static $wp_error; // Will hold global variable safely
    return isset($wp_error) ? $wp_error : ($wp_error = new WP_Error(null, null, null));
}

// displays error messages from form submissions
function write_here_show_error_messages() {
    if($codes = write_here_errors()->get_error_codes()) {
        echo '<div class="form-error">';
        // Loop error codes and display errors
        foreach($codes as $code){
            $message = write_here_errors()->get_error_message($code);
            echo '<span class="error"><strong>' . __('Error') . '</strong>: ' . $message . '</span><br/>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }   
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I did something wrong? to get the validation error message work with `WP_Error`? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Updating this for people who might have the same issue.

```
//save the new post and return its ID
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

// This will redirect you to the newly created post (Using GUID)
$post = get_post($post_id);
wp_redirect($post->guid);
exit();
```

Change above code to below code will solve the issue.

```
$errors = write_here_errors()->get_error_messages();

// only create post if there are no errors
if(empty($errors)) {
    //save the new post and return its ID
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

    if($post_id) {
        // This will redirect you to the newly created post (Using GUID)
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        wp_redirect($post->guid);
        exit();
    }
}
```